# ScalaZ: missing basic flatMap method for monad transformers? (subFlatMap)

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I have the following code:

```
def foo: OptionT[Future, String] = OptionT(Future.successful("foobar"))
def f: String => Option[Int] = s => Some(s.length)
```

I'm looking for something in the scalaz library that composes f after foo, but there are only two flatMap implementations in `OptionT` (`flatMap` and `flatMapF`), and neither has the signature I'm looking for `(A => Option[B])`.

I can implement it myself easily, e.g., `OptionT(foo.run.map(_.flatMap(f)))` for any `Functor` F, or `foo.flatMap(e => Future.succesful(f(e)))` for Future specifically (or any `Applicative` for that matter), but why is that method missing in the first place? It seems to be pretty basic functionality. Is there an import I'm missing or another place in the scalaz library where this functionality is implemented?

Thanks

EDIT: I see that Cats includes this method under `subFlatMap` https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/OptionT.scala#L54.